# Xamarin Android RelativeLayout Designer Setup

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-relativelayout, designer

Im trying to create an ListView item layout and fit an icon to the left, middle is the main text, and then two more texts that are split into two(top and bottom part of the main text height) that are on the right of the main text- but i cant seem to make it 'fit' depending on the screen size and text.

Heres my current AXML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:id="@+id/photoImageView" />
<TextView
    android:text="App Name And UID"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photoImageView"
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView" />
<TextView
    android:text="Down: 723B/s"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nameTextView"
    android:id="@+id/downloadTextView" />
<TextView
    android:text="Up: 2104MB/ss"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_below="@id/downloadTextView"
    android:id="@+id/uploadTextView" />
```

Does anyone have a solution or something im missing? Do note im trying to avoid layout nesting

Comment: Does your VS work well now? Have you test the `GridLayout`?

Comment: The VS designer never works properly, but when i build and run it its fine

Comment: So, both of the solutions are not work for you, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement that using LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout that is if your requirements allow that. You can use the layout_weight attribute to specify the size such that it always takes up that specific ratio on the screen depending on the screen size, in your example above, I have used 1(App icon) - 3(Main Text) - 2(For the last portion). This gives a total of 6, which means that the icon will always take up 1/6 of the screen width no matter the size of that screen, main text will take up 3/6 and so on. Find the code for implementing this below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:minWidth="25dp"
android:minHeight="25dp">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:id="@+id/photoImageView" />
<TextView
    android:text="App Name And UID"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:text="Down: 723B/s"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/downloadTextView" />
<TextView
    android:text="Up: 2104MB/ss"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/uploadTextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well its using **two** layouts, which isnt good performance-wise, but i guess if there is no other way , il take it!

Comment: Just did - under 15 rep it says it doesnt show though - kind of weird way of makign it

Answer (score 0):

If you just want use one layout, try [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html):

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="6">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/rr"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView" />
    <TextView
        android:text="App Name And UID"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Down: 723B/s"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/downloadTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Up: 2104MB/ss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/uploadTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: I havent had much of good luck with GridLayouts - seems that xamarin for VS is a bit broken.

Comment: Copy and paste is ok.